# How can I avoid "Output of image computation is too large" error when using cumulativeCost() function?

Tags: google-earth-engine

The following code works on smaller countries with fewer major cities (e.g. 'Zambia'), but not on larger countries with more major cities (e.g. 'South Africa'). I get the error (for the cumulativeCost() functions) that **"Output of image computation is too large... If this is a reduction, try specifying a larger 'tileScale' parameter."** It doesn't seem like the code I use allows tileScale as a parameter, is there another way to fix this?

```
var HDC = ee.FeatureCollection("users/bucklandtheresa/high_density_clusters")
var country = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0").filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'South Africa'))
HDC = HDC.filterBounds(country)
Map.addLayer(HDC, {}, 'HDC')

//SET UP IMAGES (WHICH CAN BE USED IN MAP/ITERATE)

//Major City image, Country image, min distance (cumulative cost) image):

// If HDC's are within an 15 mins driving distance (30000m), count as one city
  var createBuffers = function(feature) {
    var buffer = feature.buffer(15000)
    return buffer
  }
  var buffers = HDC.filterBounds(country).map(createBuffers)
  buffers = buffers.union(100)
  //Now must change from multiploygon to featurecollection of buffers
  var coords = buffers.first().geometry().coordinates()
  var toFeature = function(list_of_coordlist) {
    list_of_coordlist = ee.List(list_of_coordlist)
    var coordlist = list_of_coordlist.get(0)
    coordlist = ee.Geometry.Polygon([coordlist])
    coordlist = ee.Feature(coordlist)
    return coordlist
  }
  var city_clusters = coords.map(toFeature)
  city_clusters = ee.FeatureCollection(city_clusters)
  
  // Area of HDC
  var getArea = function(feature) {
    var area = feature.area()
    var centroid = feature.geometry().centroid();
    centroid = ee.Feature(centroid)
    centroid = centroid.set('area', area)
    return centroid
  }
  var Area_Centroid = HDC.map(getArea)
  //Map.addLayer(Area_Centroid, {}, 'Area_Centroid')
  
  // Add sum of interior HDC's area as property to city_clusters
  var countArea = Area_Centroid//.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['label']))
  .reduceToImage({
      properties: ['area'],
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    }).reproject('epsg:4326', null, 1000)
  var getAreaClust = function(city_cluster) {
    var img_area = countArea.clip(city_clusters)
    var img_sum = img_area.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(), city_cluster.geometry())
    var cluster_area = img_sum.get('mean')
    city_cluster = city_cluster.set('HDC_area', cluster_area)
    city_cluster = city_cluster.set('MajorCity', 1)
    return city_cluster
  }
  var city_clusters = city_clusters.map(getAreaClust)
  //Map.addLayer(city_clusters, {}, 'city_clusters_with_area')
  
  // Only those over 100km squared count as major
  MajorCities = city_clusters.filter(ee.Filter.gt('HDC_area', 100000000))
  //Map.addLayer(MajorCities, {}, 'MajorCities')
  var MajorCities = MajorCities.filterBounds(country)
  Map.addLayer(MajorCities, {}, 'MajorCities')
  
   var countryArea = country//.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['label']))
  .reduceToImage({
      properties: ['STR0_YEAR'],
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    }).reproject('epsg:4326', null, 1000)
  //Set so each pixel within country is 1
  var countryArea = countryArea.expression("b('mean') > 0 ? float(1)" + ":float(100000000000000)")
  //Map.addLayer(countryArea, {}, 'countryArea')
  
  //Convert source to image
  var MajorCitiesImage = MajorCities//.paint(MajorCities, 1)//.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['label']))
    .reduceToImage({
      properties: ['MajorCity'],
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    }).reproject('epsg:4326', null, 1000)
  //Map.addLayer(MajorCitiesImage, {}, 'MajorCitiesImg')

  //Get cumulative cost
  var Min_cumulativeCost = countryArea.cumulativeCost({
    source: MajorCitiesImage,
    maxDistance: 1000000  // 80 kilometers
  });
  
  Map.addLayer(Min_cumulativeCost, {}, 'Min_cumulativeCost')

//USE ITERATE FOR ENTIRE AREA 

var iterateFunction = function(city, prev_regions) {
  
  prev_regions = ee.FeatureCollection(prev_regions)
  city = ee.FeatureCollection([city])
  
  // Get city image
  
 var cityImage = city//.paint(MajorCities, 1)//.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['label']))
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['MajorCity'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  }).reproject('epsg:4326', null, 1000)
  
  var Min_cumulativeCostCity = countryArea.cumulativeCost({
    source: cityImage,
    maxDistance: 1000000  // 80 kilometers
  });
  //Map.addLayer(Min_cumulativeCostCity, {}, 'cumulativeCostCity')
  
  var city_region = Min_cumulativeCostCity.subtract(Min_cumulativeCost)
  
  var city_region = city_region.expression(
     "b() == 0.0 ? 1" + ":0").clip(country) 
  //Map.addLayer(city_region, {}, 'city_region')
  //print(city_region, 'city_region')
  
  // Make into vector
  var city_region = city_region.toByte();
  var city_region_vector = city_region.reduceToVectors({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
    geometry: country, 
    scale: 1000,
    maxPixels: 1e8
  });
  city_region_vector = city_region_vector.filter('label == 1')
  //city_region_vector = ee.Feature(city_region_vector): Throws errors about collections
  //Map.addLayer(city_region, {}, 'city_region')
  
  //Map.addLayer(city_region_vector, {}, 'city_region_vector')
  //Update list
  var new_regions = prev_regions.merge(city_region_vector)
  return new_regions
}

var regions = ee.FeatureCollection(MajorCities.iterate(iterateFunction, ee.FeatureCollection([])))
Map.addLayer(regions, {}, 'regions')
Map.addLayer(ee.Feature(regions.first()))
print(regions.size(), 'regionSize')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your maxDistance is 1000km, likely that's just too large of an area for the cumulative cost algorithm.  However, it looks like you're just computing distances against a constant of map of 1s, so it looks like you could just use distance instead of cumulative cost (and avoid several rasterizing steps) or fastDistanceTransform.

(Also, you don't need and shouldn't use iterate.  Use map instead).

Comment: Thanks Noel! I want the distance formula to not cross borders (so outside of the borders there's a high cost), which is why I think I had to use cumulative cost instead of distance. An additional complication is that if I do a lower maxDistance, it may not cover the whole country. Just to clarify: I'm trying to divide countries into regions based on their closest major city, without crossing borders - do you think this is possible for large countries?

Answer (score 0):

I found that exporting regions works, and will do large countries in less than an hour.

```
Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: regions,
  description: 'Regions_SouthAfrica',
  assetId: 'Regions_SouthAfrica',
});
```